# JBoss Service with SSL and Protocol Buffers

Tags: ssl, jboss, service, protocol-buffers

I'm interested in building a JBoss service. Because I'm reusing some existing code, the service must be able to talk SSL/TLS and Protocol Buffers.

The documentation I see on the [JBoss wiki](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossService) makes it look like services have their transport and data interpretation handled by JBoss itself. Is it really the case?

How could I implement this requirement?

Regards,

M-A